# How to get the Address of a Draft SMS

Tags: android, sms

iam not able to get the address of the draft SMS, it always giving me `null` iam using the following code

```
 public static final Uri SMS_PROVIDER = Uri.parse("content://sms");     
     Cursor oCursorSMS = mContext.getContentResolver().query(SMS_PROVIDER, null,null,null, null);                                                           
oCursorSMS.moveToFirst();                                     
        final String[] columns = oCursorSMS.getColumnNames();                           
        for (int i = 0; i < columns.length; i++) {
            String ss = cursor.getString(i);
            }
```

when iam reading a Draft SMS the Address Column returns `null` i have searched alot, there are alot of questions about this issue but no one have answer. can anyone help me with this

Comment: Did you get the answer..I am also facing the same issue..If you know the answer.Please share here

Comment: i didn't find the answer but now iam deppending on reading the "address" column if it is 'Null', then is it Draft

Comment: @AnasBakez...Vikki's solution is perfect for me.

Answer (score 7):

From the uri `content://mms-sms/conversations?simple=true` you can access the threads table, in the threads table there is a column `recipient_ids`  which you can use to get the address, see my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12492602/fetch-address-from-canonical-addresses-table/12493252#12493252) to know how to do that. Basically, you want to get the `thread_id` from your sms and then use it to do a look on the threads table, i.e the filter should be `_id = thread_id_from_sms`. Now get the recipient_ids and use it to look up the address from `content://mms-sms/canonical-addresses`