# Fetch address from "canonical_addresses" table

Tags: android, android-contentprovider

I am working on an Android application. I fetched recipient_id from the following uri.

```
content://mms-sms/conversations?simple=true
```

Now I want to fetch the address from canonical_addresses`" table using the recipient id. But I don't have any idea to query canonical_addresses table"`. I searched a lot in web. Please help me to find a solution friends.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Canonical table has two columns, `_id` and `address`. When you get recipient id you do a lookup for that id in the canonical addresses table. For multiple recipients the ids are separated by a space, so you'll have to split the result like

`recipient_ids.split(" ")`

and lookup each id.

```
getContentResolver().query(Uri.parse("content://mms-sms/canonical-addresses"), null, "_id = " + recipientId, null, null);
```

or

```
getContentResolver().query(Uri.parse("content://mms-sms/canonical-address/" + recipientId), null, null, null, null);
```

Comment: hey @Vikki, what if you want to get the thread_id from the uri "content://mms-sms/conversations?simple=true".  How would you do that?

Comment: Nevermind, i guess the '_id' column of "content://mms-sms/conversations?simple=true" is equivalent to the 'thread_id' column of "content://mms-sms/conversations" .

Comment: @toobsco42 yes that is the actual threads table so _id is the equivalent of thread_id in other tables

Comment: Just tried this and it's almost right. The second URI should read `"content://mms-sms/canonical-address/" + recipientId` Note "address", not "addresses".

Comment: I would also add that recipientIds are always sorted. :)) like this : 23 302 502.
So if you want to search for group thread. You will sort id's insert spaces there and search it.

Answer (score 2):

```
message = contentResolver.query(uri, null,null, null,SORT_ORDER);
            if(message != null){
                while (message.moveToNext()) {
                        String id = message.getString(message.getColumnIndex("_id"));
                        String thid = message.getString(message.getColumnIndex("thread_id"));
                        String phoneNumber = message.getString(message.getColumnIndex("address"));
                        String person = message.getString(message.getColumnIndex("person"));
                        //String present = message.getString(message.getColumnIndex("reply_path_present"));
                        //Log.v("sms "+thid,id);
                        //Log.v("sms "+present,present);
                        if(phoneNumber !=null ){
                                //if(phoneNumber.contains("-"))
                                    phoneNumber=phoneNumber.replaceAll("[-() ]", "");
                        }
                        else
                        {
                             Cursor c =contentResolver.query(Uri.parse("content://mms-sms/conversations?simple=true"), null, "_id = " + thid, null, null);
                             //getContentResolver().query(Uri.parse("content://mms-sms/canonical-addresses"), null, "_id = " + recipientId, null, null);
                             if(c.moveToNext())
                             {

                                 phoneNumber = c.getString(3);
                                 if(phoneNumber !=null ){
                                        //if(phoneNumber.contains("-"))
                                     Log.v(" id=>" +id+ " thid=>"+thid +" first = > " , c.getString(3));
                                }
                             }
                             c.close();
                             c =contentResolver.query(Uri.parse("content://mms-sms/canonical-addresses"), null, "_id = " + phoneNumber, null, null);
                             if(c.moveToNext())
                             {
                                 Log.v(thid +" second = > " , c.getString(1));
                                 phoneNumber = c.getString(1);
                                 phoneNumber=phoneNumber.replaceAll("[-() ]", "");
                             }
                             c.close();
```