# canonical-addresses in android 1.6 api level 4?

Tags: android, sms

How can I get canonical-addresses in android 1.6 (api level 4)?
both content://sms/canonical-addresses/ and content://sms/canonical-address/ return null!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/12493252/1168654

Comment: the link you provided guide me to this exception: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Unrecognized URI:content://mms-sms/canonical-addresses/

Comment: if i remove mms from the uri the exception removed too but contentResolver return null!

Comment: at last the answer is: we cannot access canonical-addresses in api level 4 so we need to join sms and threads implicitly. that's it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

at last the answer is: we cannot access canonical-addresses in api level 4 so we need to join sms and threads implicitly. that's it.
there is a column called thread_id in sms table which is a foreign key for primary key of threads table _id.